# .net website in iis7 not rendering correctly on one server but is fine on another

Tags: .net, iis-7, ajaxcontroltoolkit, webforms

I am trying to deploy an asp.net 4.0 website that uses web forms to 2 different windows 2008 servers running iis 7. On the first machine it is deployed to everything works great however on the second machine it is deployed to the web site is not rendering correctly (formatting is off, asp menu doesn't respond, post backs don't work). What is strange is if I run the website on the second machine in "Compatability View" in IE it works fine (this should not matter though bc I am forcing the website to run in IE9 in the markup). Same code is pushed to both machines and same IIS setup on both machines, and like I said on machine 1 everything renders ok without "Compatability View" on so I know that is not a problem.

Digging into this I ran F12 developer tools on the website from each server. When comparing everything that gets loaded you will see the website on the second machine not working is missing 3 scriptresource.axd files compared to the first machine. (screen shot below). I believe these are generated from the AJAX control toolkit.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the second machine is rendering the website differently or why those scriptresource files would not be getting loaded. The website files are identical including web.config.

Any suggestions?

(note machine 2 that is not working is image on left below missing script resource files, machine 1 that is working fine is on right below)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved... Ran the hotfix described in this post by Scott Hanselman dealing with a bug in the browser definition files with .net 4.0.

[Bug and Fix: ASP.NET fails to detect IE10 causing _doPostBack is undefined JavaScript error or maintain FF5 scrollbar position](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)